# Find minimum sampling rate of non-ideal notch filter

Tags: filters, frequency, sampling, nyquist

Old test problem:

"*You have been asked to design a real-time digital filtering system that eliminates a band of frequencies between 20 and 30 MHz but preserves everything else.  The system uses an analog-to-digital converter (ADC) to digitize the analog input, a digital signal processing chip (DSP) to filter the digitized signal, and a digital-to-analog (DAC) converter to convert the signal back to analog.  Assume that ideal sampling is used as well as ideal anti-aliasing and reconstruction filters.  The maximum frequency that needs to be preserved in the reconstructed analog signal is 90 MHz.*

*What is the lowest sampling rate allowable in this system given the above constraints and giving that the anti-aliasing and reconstruction filters are not quite ideal:  they have 6 MHz transition bands?*"

If it was non-ideal it would be the Nyquist equation:

fs > 2*fmax

where fmax = 90 MHz, so,

fs > 2*90MHz

fs > 180 MHz

In the non-ideal situation, my thought would be to add the 6 MHz transition bands to fmax.  Since it is a notch filter there are two transition bands.  Meaning it would be

90 MHz + 6 MHz + 6 MHz = 102 MHz

I was told that the correct set-up to solve this problem is as follows:

fs > 2*(90MHz + (6MHz/2))

fs > 2*(93)

fs > 186

He mentioned something about not caring whether the transition bands overlap.

My question is why is the 6 MHz transition band divided by 2?  Is it because there are two transition bands?  And if it were a highpass or lowpass filter, where there is only one transition band, would it not be necessary to divide by two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sample at 2*93 = 186 MHz, then the frequencies from 93 to 96 MHz will alias into the range from 90 to 93 MHz. However, since the problem requires that only frequencies from 0 to 90 MHz are preserved, you are not concerned with aliasing occuring after 90 MHz.

Comment: Ok, so in the case of a high pass filter, say the frequency is passed from 30 to 90 MHz with the same 6 MHz transition, it would also be 186 MHz.  Correct?

Comment: I believe so, yes. A high pass filter at 30 MHz will not introduce any aliasing or change your sampling frequency in any way (unless you do bandpass sampling, but that's a different problem).